# Trying to write some razor code to define a CSS class in a Razor view, pretty simple, but getting confused

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am trying to define a CSS class on a  depending on a condition, in a razor view. Must be simple, but I am struggling with it.

Code so far is:

```
        <tr class="@{if (id == 0) {@:selected} else {@:notselected}}">
```

Obviously missing something simple....

Thoughts appreciated....

Comment: You should, and it'll be simpler, to get your controller to calculate this and then just populate a property in your model for selected

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Good to know the ideal approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<tr class="@((id == 0) ? "selected" : "notselected")">
```

Answer (score 2):

What I do in that kind of situations is

```
@{
   string rowClass = id == 0 ? "selected" : "notselected";
}

<tr class="@rowClass">
```

Anyways, if you want that inline, you could use

```
 <tr class="@(id == 0 ? "selected" : "notselected")">
```

Comment: Like the extra advice. Thanks. I have a number of conditions to test, so in my case inline is best.